# multiple QT applications on an embedded ARM Linux platform

Tags: qt, arm

I compiled QT 5.13 on an embedded ARM Linux platform and encountered an issue when running two QT applications, A and B. Here are the symptoms:

1. Two cursors appear on the screen.
2. When I move the cursor, both applications refresh their UI, causing the lower-level A application to overwrite the UI of the upper-level B application, as if drawing with a cursor.

I tried using

```
QWindow::fromWinId(qstr.toUInt())
```

to embed application B into application A, but I received the error message

```
QWindow::fromWinId(): platform plugin does not support foreign windows. 
QWindowContainer: embedded window cannot be null.
```

How can I resolve the issue of running multiple QT applications on an embedded ARM Linux platform? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you using a windowing environment like X or wayland? Embedded apps usually assume they take control of the entire screen.

Comment: You probably want to look at something like the [Qt Wayland Compositor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwaylandcompositor-index.html).

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this.  You can use a window manager (of which a compositor is a variant).  However, much depends on the hardware and application.  For instance you can see that cell phone UIs are much different than a PC window manager.  The limited screen real estate and touch versus mouse are reasons for this.  Just having multiple applications is not enough.  Are the applications limited to just A/B?  Then you can code the window management yourself... etc.

Comment: there is no  windowing environment in my Embedded linux